# Difference between timestamps in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am identifying the difference between two timestamp fields in Oracle.

(TIMESTAMPa-TIMESTAMPb)

Result: +09 19:16:04.747000

I am attempting to note whether the resulting value is positive or negative.

My current solution works, but I think there has to be a better way.

Solution:

```
CASE
WHEN SUBSTR((TIMESTAMPa-TIMESTAMPb),1,1)='+' 
THEN 'AFTER'
ELSE 'BEFORE'
END AS DIFF
```

Comment: Do you need the actual difference (as interval), or *only* which is later? What if the timestamps are the same, do you treat a zero interval as positive or negative? (It would be reported as `+0 00:...` but is that what you want?)

Comment: i am only concerned with the +/- value. in this instance it would not be possible to have a zero value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`interval '0' day` can be replaced by any other '0' interval

```
select  case 
            when (timestamp '2017-02-01 20:07:09' - timestamp '2017-02-01 21:35:02') > interval '0' day 
            then 'AFTER' 
            else 'BEFORE' 
        end

from    dual
```

> BEFORE

... but why not use a direct compare?

```
select  case 
            when timestamp '2017-02-01 20:07:09' > timestamp '2017-02-01 21:35:02' 
            then 'AFTER' 
            else 'BEFORE' 
        end

from    dual
```

> BEFORE

Comment: both of these work and the second is as you put it simply, it didn't even occur to me. thank you!